# Rails <% if signed_in? %> not finding current_user in Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I'm working through rails and my Signed_in? method isn't working

in the .html.erb

```
<% if signed_in? %>
```

here is my session controller

```
module SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user)
  remember_token = User.new_remember_token
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
  user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
  self.current_user = user
end

def signed_in?

p "TRYING TO SIGN IN"
p !current_user.nil?
p current_user
p self.current_user
p @current_user
p self.current_user

!current_user.nil?

end

def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end
def current_user?(user)
  user == current_user
end  
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
end
```

I added a print statement.

Currently they are returning in the log

```
"TRYING TO SIGN IN"
false
nil
nil
nil
nil
```

any idea why this is and how to fix it?

THanks

Comment: any error you found from `<% if signed_in? %>` ? If no, how do you understand it is not working..?

Comment: I understand that it is returning false, but I'm not sure why. I expect the current_user to return the signed_in user

Comment: It's printing the stuff you print in the method you say Rails isn't finding.

Comment: Rails is finding the method, but not the current user? so it prints values meaning it's running the method, but the values are nil, because it can't find the correct data or I'm not save it correctly

Comment: Have you tried debugging/binding.pry/etc to figure out why it isn't being set the way you expect?

Comment: not sure what that is?

Answer (score 0):

The remember_token stored in database is encrypted

```
user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
```

---

You are trying to find a user with the clear-text version, this is like trying to compare "token_1" with "laskj5dflkasjdflkas4djf1la134232sdk2jf"

use

```
@current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token]))
```

EDIT: Is there a reason why you use a cookie and not session storage?